# Workaround for dash-ssh/click/python3 clash

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, dask

I am unable to run dask-ssh because of the click/python3 clash. I have LC_ALL and LANG set as recommended but click still objects. I recognise that this is a click/python3 problem but I hope that someone has seen and solved this.

```
$ env | grep LC_ALL
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
$ env | grep LANG
LANG=C.UTF-8
$ dask-ssh localhost
Your terminal does not properly support unicode text required by command    line
utilities running Python 3.  This is commonly solved by specifying encoding
environment variables, though exact solutions may depend on your system:

    $ export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
    $ export LANG=C.UTF-8

For more information see: http://click.pocoo.org/5/python3/
```

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Coming in from my MacBook Pro, LANG should be en_GB.UTF-8. It is passed over via ssh so I had to avoid setting it on the host and then it all works correctly.

Comment: These settings might need to be applied to all of the target machines as well.  Often environment variables are not carried over when you use SSH.  Arguably this is something that dask-ssh should be able to handle on its own.  I doubt that that is the case now though.

Comment: Hi Matt, they do appear to cascade properly from qsub to dask-ssh.

Comment: qsub may be using different mechanisms than ssh.  You may also find https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1260 of interest